# File handling BST in c

Tags: c

Please see the code below. All input is read from file. The first line contains `X` denoting the number of test case. Each test case contains 2 lines. The first line contains `N` distinct integers (space separated). The second line contains integer `NUM`. In this code I need to display every test case in a separate `inorder` BST.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *fp=fopen("file.txt","r");
struct btnode
{
    int value;
    struct btnode *l;
    struct btnode *r;
}*root = NULL, *temp = NULL, *t2, *t1;

void insert();
void inorder(struct btnode *t);
void create();
void s(struct btnode *t);
int flag = 1;

void insert()
{
    create();
    if (root == NULL) 
        root = temp;
    else    
        s(root);
}

void create()
{
    int data;
    fscanf(fp,"%d", &data);
    temp = (struct btnode *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct btnode));
    temp->value = data;
    temp->l = temp->r = NULL;
}

void inorder(struct btnode *t)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        printf("No elements in a tree to display");
        return;
    }
    if (t->l != NULL)    
        inorder(t->l);
        printf("%d -> ", t->value);
    if (t->r != NULL)    
        inorder(t->r);
}

void s(struct btnode *t)
{
    if ((temp->value > t->value) && (t->r != NULL))
        s(t->r);
    else if ((temp->value > t->value) && (t->r == NULL))
        t->r = temp;
    else if ((temp->value < t->value) && (t->l != NULL))
        s(t->l);
    else if ((temp->value < t->value) && (t->l == NULL))
        t->l = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int ch,n,x;
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("File Missing");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%d",&x);
        for(int j=0;j<x;j++)
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%d",&n);
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                insert();
            }
            printf("Set %d: ",j+1);
            inorder(root);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
Sample file input:
2
7
4 5 2 77 18 3 6
6
34 3 2 0 6 4

Output:
Set 1: 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 18 -> 77 ->
Set 2: 0 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 6 -> 34 ->
```

Comment: Can you provide *any* information about your "little problem"?  Sample input, expected vs actual output?

Comment: @ScottHunter sample file input is the value inside my textfile while Output is the final output of my code

Comment: What is your problem?  What is in the file?  What is the *expected* output?

Comment: @ScottHunter I already inputted the values inside of my textfile and my expected output. you can see it at the last part of my code.

Comment: No one else can reproduce the problem w/o the *contents* of the input file; no one else can tell how the code needs to change if they don't know what it is *supposed* to produce for output.

Comment: this is the content of my file.
2 - NUMBER OF TEST CASE(T)
7 - TOTAL NUMBER OF VALUES(N)
4 5 2 77 18 3 6 - INTEGER VALUES(NUM)
6 - TOTAL NUMBER OF VALUES(N)
34 3 2 0 6 4 - INTEGER VALUES(NUM)    .  You can see it at the last part of my code

Comment: What.  Is.  The.  Problem. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a condition to separate your 1st and 2nd set, and create a multiple BST. You must have  this condition that when (i==n) break;  to create another BST for the 2nd set and so on.